# I don't understand the error message - Streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that I wrote on other computer and it was running smoothly. because I needed to change computers, I cloned it from my repo to the new computer and created directory with env for it, However I am not able to run it. executing the below running code gives the below error

```
streamlit run app.py
```

I am getting the below error, can someone please help explain what is error trying to tell me?

```
(venv) C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA>streamlit run app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\cli.py", line 204, in main_run
    _main_run(target, args, flag_options=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\cli.py", line 232, in _main_run
    command_line = _get_command_line_as_string()
  File "C:\Users\CLAHAXY8W\PycharmProjects\charting_with_streamlit\charting_using_Streamlit_EDA\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\cli.py", line 221, in _get_command_line_as_string
    cmd_line_as_list.extend(click.get_os_args())
AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'get_os_args'
```

Comment: somewhere in your code you have the instruction `cmd_line_as_list.extend(click.get_os_args())`. what the error tells you is that `get_os_args` is not recognized. You have some object callied `click`  that doesn;t have a method named `get_os_args`

Comment: Either the new computer has an old version of the `click` module (whatever that is), or you made your own file named `click.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, where the Click module made a breaking change without increasing its semantic version.

Pin `click==8.0` in your requirements file or upgrade Streamlit above 1.8.1

https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/attributeerror-module-click-has-no-attribute-get-os-args/23621/12